# How to load plugin after page is loaded - pagespeed issues

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript, performance, fonts

is there a way to load a plugin, after the whole page is rendered and fully loaded?

I have horrible pagespeed according to Google and webpagetools. One plugin *(provenexpert)*, is **loading several fonts and loads of JS**.

Is there a way to use this plugin but prevent the bad loading times?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd reach out directly to that plugin developer to relate your concerns, and if they're not responsive consider a different plugin. But in the meantime, you can use [`wp_dequeue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/) and [`wp_dequeue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/) and their counterparts wp_enqueue_script/style to remove the stuff that's slowing down your site.

This answer has more detail on how to move scripts from the header to the footer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212274/16

To find the IDs of the styles/scripts you're trying to move using those functions, View Source and look at the ID, for instance:

1. `<link rel='stylesheet' id='eo-leaflet.js-css'  href='https://....` or
2. `<link rel='stylesheet' id='mystyles-css-css'  href='https://...` or
3. `<script type='text/javascript' id='coblocks-lightbox-js' src='https://...` or
4. `<script type='text/javascript' id='pluginname-script-js' src='https://...`

The trick is, WordPress automatically appends -css to stylesheet IDs and -js to script IDs, so you need to IGNORE the trailing -css and -js in the examples above when figuring out their IDs. The actual IDs you'd use for wp_dequeue_script/style etc would be:

1. eo-leaflet.js
2. mystyles-css
3. coblocks-lightbox
4. pluginname-script

If you still run into issues removing them, the next thing to check is the hook being used (the add_action part in the answer referenced above). Plugins/themes use a variety of these to insert their scripts/styles so you have to adjust accordingly when trying to remove them. This answer uses different add_action calls that might work better than the ones in the previous answer:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/202895/16

(You put all this in the functions.php file of your theme.)